# jQuery Dimming the Background

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to dim the background when my pop up window appears...?

The visitor will be reading the FAQ page, then a pop up window will fade in asking if visitor would like to sign up on the email list.

You can see it [here](http://halloweenseattle.com/faq_test.php)

THEN, I'd like the background to dim, so the viewer's attention is on the box.

Then when they enter their email address or click "close," it UN-dims (goes back to normal) and pop up window disappears.

So my main question is how to make the background dim?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all the non popup contents in a wrapper div (e.g., id="wrapperDiv"), and then fadeTo desired opacity on the callback of the popup fading in or opening, for example:

```
$("#popup").fadeIn(500, function () {
    $("#wrapperDiv").fadeTo("slow", 0.5); //or whatever desired opacity
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The background is dimmed by a DIV covering the entire screen with an opacity. For your purposes you can either write this yourself or look at a library like this one that will give you that functionality out of the box: http://flaviusmatis.github.io/easyModal.js/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your html

```
<div class="div_popup_overlay"></div>
```

And Css

```
.div_popup_overlay {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #333;
opacity: .7;
z-index: 3000;
}
```

when you open the popup window, show `div_popup_overlay` div and when close popup hide it.